# Service restart failed, but successful in second attempt

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I try to restart services on Windows with following command:

```
Start-Service -Name '$service_name' -verbose
```

Restart attempts sometimes fail, but sometimes successful with the same command in case of the same service. I don't understand how it is possible, that I sometimes can't start a service with same command.

Comment: Look into event logs to get the reason. From Win+R, type "eventvwr" cmd, press Enter. In the event logs window, go to "Windows Logs"->"System" and go through the logs to find your service name and the error while starting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised you mentioned it worked sometimes. You pass the name as a literal string with single quotes, which means the variable $service_name is not translated. And so it should not find the service name.

Try removing the quotes: `Start-Service -Name $service_name -verbose`

Comment: By the way it is working, like in this case:
`Start-Service -Name 'ShellHWDetection' -verbose`
"VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Start-Service" on target "Shell Hardware Detection (ShellHWDetection)"."

Comment: Indeed, however you are passing the name of the service directly, not via a variable :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't set the name directly in this case. :) It is used with `Invoke-Command`.